# jQuery - append() method is not working properly because of the space

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery code like this:

```
$('#dataset_list').append("<option value="+data[i]['fields']['name']+">"+data[i]['fields']['name']+"</option>")
```

Now problem is that if `data[i]['fields']['name']`include a space inside.

for example `data[i]['fields']['name'] = "big city"`
It will only put `big` in the value attribute.

I know it's okay that I just limit the user not to put the space for input. But is there any way that I could solve the problem?

Answer (score 6):

Wrap the value within quotes otherwise the value after space would take as a new attribute.

```
$('#dataset_list').append("<option value='"+data[i]['fields']['name']+"'>"+data[i]['fields']['name']+"</option>")
//                                     --^--                         --^--
```

---

Or you can generate the [DOM element using jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes) and then append using [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) method.

```
$('<option/>', {
  text: data[i]['fields']['name'],
  value: data[i]['fields']['name']
}).appendTo('#dataset_list');
```

Comment: @Pwan : glad to help :)

Comment: @PranavCBalan second method is interesting! Thank you!

Comment: Strange but you really neet to wrap it in double quotes `"`, not in single `'`. As this doesn't seem to work (firefox v59 windows 7)...

Answer (score 2):

I think, following will be a more safer and cleaner approach ( Added comments for clarity):

```
// create an 'option' element on the fly and assign it to variable $opt
var $opt = $('<option/>');  

// this goes to value attribute for option
$opt.val(data[i]['fields']['name']);  

// this is display text for option
$opt.text(data[i]['fields']['name']); 

// now, append the new element to your #data_list element
$('#dataset_list').append($opt);
```